# Check token expiration without requesting API

Tags: angular, jwt

I develop an `Angular` web application and I have recently added to it a JWT security to be sure that requests are done by authorized users.

My implementation of the JWT is really simple; the user connect himself to the application, a token is created and returned in the body response of the POST request and then this token and his expiration date are stored by `Angular` application in `LocalStorage`.

Following the courses, the tutorials and all the helpers to integrate JWT to an Angular application with a NodeJS API, I have figured out that there is no way, as far as I have seen, to check the expiration of the token directly inside of the Angular app.

I have tried to imagine a way by subscribing to a `Subject`, but how to apply a new value to the subject when the expiration comes.

I also got a method to know the actual date in millisecond minus the expiration one but don't really know how to use it to have a real time information.

And I wonder if there could be a way to create something like middleware, as well as in the API. But doing it for the whole methods of the application might be really painful.

So what I need is to have the expiration information without doing a HTTP request. With a request I will have a `401` error but some actions can be done without doing any request. So I don't want the user to do anything if the token has expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an observable that emit when you log in or log out, here's something to get you started. It's not super clean with the setTimeout, but should be a good base.

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthenticationService {
  public authenticated$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private expirationTimeout: number | undefined;

  // Call when you authenticate with your JWT
  authenticate(jwt: string): void {
    this.authenticated$.next(true);

    const expiration = getJwtExpiration(jwt);
    const timeout = +expiration - +new Date();

    if (this.expirationTimeout !== undefined) {
        clearTimeout(this.expirationTimeout);
    }

    this.expirationTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.authenticated$.next(false);
    }, timeout);
  }

  // Call when you log out
  logout() {
    if (this.expirationTimeout !== undefined) {
        clearTimeout(this.expirationTimeout);
        this.expirationTimeout = undefined;
    }
    this.authenticated$.next(false);
  }
}

@Component({
  template: `<span *ngIf="authService.authenticated$ | async">
    Only visible when authenticated
  </span>`
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(
    public authService: AuthenticationService
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: Doing with a `setTimeout` works fine thanks. If you could edit your post to have only the setTimeout method it could be great, because as I said the JWT information is stored in the `LocalStorage`, so this is not useful for your answer. I will then accept it :)